# How can I have a D-Link router intercept requests for a certain page?

Tags: networking, http

I have a D-Link router, and I was wondering how I could intercept requests on my router for a page. I would like to have it so whenever someone on my network goes to the page (for example, http://google.com/waffles) it returns something like "Hello!" with specific headers. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* to use your router to do something like this. I suggest ARP Spoofing, and [Dsniff](http://www.monkey.org/~dugsong/dsniff/)

If you would like to go about this via more conventional means, then you will have to see if you can load custom os on your router. Check and see if your router is [compatible](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start) with OpenWRT.